# Rellenar Input php con array de elementos seleccionados jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html5

tengo el siguiente problema, existe un programa que crea los turnos de trabajo de la empresa con un correturnos, el caso es que lo tengo que actualizar porque ya hay 3 correturnos
El html es:

```
<input type="text" name="Correturnostarde[]" id="Correturnostarde" hidden value="">
```

```html
<table id="trabajadores2">
    <tbody>
      <tr data-trab="159"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="330"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="332"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="337"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="345"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="367"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="370"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="378"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="379"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="380"></tr>
      <tr data-trab="381"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Y en el Jquery:

```js
$('#trabajadores2').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected-row")) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected-row');
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass('selected-row');
    }
    var data = $(this).attr("data-trab");
    var linea=document.getElementById("Correturnostarde");
    linea.value=data;
});
```

Lo que necesito es guardar todos los valores de "data-trab" de los elementos con la clase "Selected-rows" en un array para enviarlos a mi php, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes agregarlos al mismo tiempo que actualizas la clase
Html:
        
Jquery:

```
var arr=[];
$('#trabajadores2').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected-row")) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected-row');
        // aqui veiramos en que posicion esta el elemento en el array
        index = arr.indexOf($(this).attr('data-trab'));
        //y aqui lo quitamos del array
        removed = arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass('selected-row');
        //aqui incluimos el elemento en el array
        arr.push($(this).attr('data-trab'));
    }
    $('#Correturnostarde').val(arr)
});
```

Comment: Buenas, no me funciona, meda undefined si hago un console.log(arr) y no me borra del array solo me añade cuando hago click

Comment: mmm, juega con el arr.splice (funcion de javascript) tambien puede sponer un alert luego de que remueves la clase 'selected row' para verificar que estas entrando a la funcion.. plus, como sabes que los agrega al array si te arroja undefined?

Comment: ya lo he arreglado de oto modo, con un console.log se que no me borra el array y solo incluye